# Problem opening Natural earth quick start for QGIS

Tags: qgis, natural-earth

Trying to open the file "Natural_Earth_quick_start_for_QGIS.qgs" a window opens, listing 20 "bad layers". The window is entitled "Handle bad layers". Consequently I cannot even get started with Natural Earth in QGIS, although all advice I find assumes that opening this project is a piece of cake. what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

If the `Handle bad Layers` dialogue comes up, the software can not find the datasources at the place they were stored in the .qgs file.

You can open the .qgs file with a text editor, look out for the path and file names, and look on your disk if they are present. If not, you have to install them manually, or move them to the desired place.

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. The various files were elsewhere. Please pardon my appalling ignorance.